# how to run WixSilentExecCmdLine to run batfil ein background

Tags: installation, wix, custom-action, wix3.10

I am trying to run a bat file in background while installing an app using WIX. For this I used WixSilentExecCmdLine but after writing this code sniphet Installationitself failed.

```
<Property Id="WixSilentExecCmdLine" Value="C:\SampleWix\myBat.bat" Hidden="yes"/>
<CustomAction Id="SilentExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixSilentExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SilentExecExample" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Light Command

```
    %WIX_LIGHT% %INSTALLER_BUILD_DIR%\*.wixobj -o %OUTPUT_DIR%\%MSI_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME% -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to run another parallel install while in the ExecuteSequence. Windows installer has a limitation that only one install can be in the ExecuteSequence at one time.

Please see this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/175170/why-windows-installer-can-only-install-a-single-program-at-a-time).